# Am trying to set a header Content-Type = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', but getting error

Tags: karate

Am trying to set a header `Content-Type = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'`, but getting the below error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MIME type may not contain reserved characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please omit the charset part, it should work.

```
* header Content-Type = 'application/json'
```